# How to compare values in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie to angular, so I need a help.

In html, I wrote the following

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="Email" id="LoginEmail class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>


<div class="form-group">                                        
 <input type="password" name="password" id="LoginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>                                   
</div>
```

In angular, I write the following code

```
angular
    .module("LoginForm", [])
    .controller("processingLoginForm", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

        $scope.userinfo = [
            {name : "User1", 
             account : "user1@whatever.com", 
             city: "XYZ", 
             password: "Angular@2017"}
        ];

    }]);
```

I need to compare the value of input box with the value of the script and show a message if it's not correct, so how can I do that?

Comment: with "===" as always

Comment: I don't know where to but my controller and model and how to access the values of the array

Comment: wich version of angular 1, 2, 4, 5?

Comment: FYI, use `ng-model` attribute to bind data in order to access from the controller

Comment: I'm using angular1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to assign model to your template scope. Use `ng-model` for this purpose. Then you need a form to submit and trigger a function to check if user input matches to the desired values.

Add `ng-model` and wrap your inputs with a form tag:

```
<form ng-submit="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input ng-model="email" type="email" name="Email" id="LoginEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" id="LoginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

Check if user input is valid in Controller:

```
  $scope.login = function() {
        const isUserValid = $scope.email === $scope.userinfo[0].account && $scope.password === $scope.userinfo[0].password;
    if(isUserValid) {
            alert("Logged In Successfully");
        }else {
        alert("Email or password incorrect. Try again.")
    }
  }
```

Here's a [working example of the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/x5fpr2pa/).

Comment: Thanks alot... you do a great job

Answer (score 0):

In your input elements you miss the ng-model attribute. It is used to bind the values with your scope variables.

```
<input type="email" ... ng-model="email" ...>
<input type="password" ... ng-model="password" ...>
```

And in your controller you can write

```
if($scope.email == $scope.userinfo[0].account && $scope.password == $scope.userinfo[0].password){
    //Login ok
}else{
    //Login failed
}
```

Comment: I need to compare the value of scope with the value of input from the user such scope.email === inputvalue

Comment: Check the updated answer, you just need to get values from the scope variable you already have and compare with the ones coming from ng-model

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming there is a form element somewhere above

Add `ng-submit` to it

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
```

> Add `ng-model` to the form elements.

I have added `state.email` and `state.password`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input ng-model="state.email" type="email" name="Email" id="LoginEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                        
   <input ng-model="state.password" type="password" name="password" id="LoginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>                                   
</div>
```

> Compare the binding values to the values in `$scope.userinfo`

```
angular
.module("LoginForm", [])
.controller("processingLoginForm", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.userinfo = [{
         name : "User1", 
         account : "user1@whatever.com", 
         city: "XYZ", 
         password: "Angular@2017"
    }];

    // when you submit the form, this function will be called
    $scope.submit = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($scope.state.email !== $scope.userinfo[0].account || $scope.state.password !== $scope.userinfo[0].password) {
        // did not match
      } else {
        // matched
      }
    }
}]);
```